# display last days of previous month php

Tags: php, mysql

I searched the millions of similar posts about this but cannot find how to make it count down from 31, 30, 29, 28 etc.

I can have the previous calendar blocks show the 31st but that's all. I need it to show previous month 31st, 30, 29, etc.

updated code from Renku:

```
    //define the variable dayCol
    $dayCol = 0;

    // Print last months' days spots.
    for ($i=0; $i<$leadInDays; $i++) {

    $lastmonth = date('d', strtotime(-$i.' day', strtotime($startDate))); // Days in previous month

    print "<td width=\"14%\" height=\"25%\" class=\"calendar_cell_disabled_middle\">$lastmonth</td>\n ";

    $dayCol++;
}
```

example : [image]

Comment: start with `for ($i=$leadInDays; $i>0; $i--) {` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing a new loop for this.

```
 <?php

    $StartDate= date("Y-F-d",strtotime("+0 Month"));// get first day of current month

    $num= 10; // how many past days you need from previous month + 1 (to remove current day)

    for ($i=1; $i<$num; $i++) {

    echo $prev= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(-$i.' day', strtotime($StartDate)))."<br />"; //get last days of previous month

}

    ?>
```

I am re writing it with your loop,

```
<?php

$dayCol = 0;

$leadInDays = 5; // (just for February cuz theres 5 blanks before its the 1st of Feb)

$StartDate= date("Y-F-d",strtotime("+0 Month"));

// Print last months' days spots.
for ($i=1; $i<($leadInDays+1); $i++) {

    $lastmonth = date('d', strtotime(-$i.' day', strtotime($StartDate))); // Days in previous month

    print "<td width=\"14%\" height=\"25%\" class=\"calendar_cell_disabled_middle\">$lastmonth</td>\n ";

    $dayCol++;
}
?>
```

Test it [Here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Comment: when i use your $lastmonth = date('d', strtotime(-$i.' day', strtotime($startDate)));  it counts backwards 31 - 30 - 29 - 28 - 27 -1 - 2 - 3 - 4

Comment: $leadInDays = 5; // (just for February cuz theres 5 blanks before its the 1st of Feb)

Comment: i ran your code with the test-link you provide and it results: 31 30 29 28 27

Comment: it is correct I hope... Its february, and output is Jan-31-27. Isnt that you need?

Comment: my $startDate = mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year);

Comment: yes but in calendar format.. so if u look at calendar last Sunday should be Jan 27th.. but with your code it shows last Sunday as Jan 31st

Comment: didnt get u.. How u got Jan 31st as sunday from the code, since it returns `31-30-29-28-27`...!!!

Comment: and $i has to be $i=0 in the for statement: for ($i=0; $i<$leadInDays; $i++) {  or else it displays wrong last month day spots

Comment: That, `sunday-saturday` placed in a  `<tr>` has nothing to do with my code.. :) I just gave last `n` days of the previous month as you asked. If you need to get days from dates you can get it from `date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $requested_month, $requested_day, $requested_year));` and can place it in your `<tr>` using an another  loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24072/discussion-between-rubberchicken-and-renku)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `date('t')` to get the number of days in said month and just loop backwards:

```
$month = '2013-02-05';

for($i = date('t', strtotime($month)); $i > 0; $i--) {
  ...
}
```